# ZeroMQ what is XREQ and XREP?

Tags: zeromq

Can somebody explain in details how XREQ and XREP work? I was trying to find some explanation on ZeroMQ web-site but without luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XREQ/XREP are aliases for ROUTER/DEALER. XREQ/XREP were used in ZeroMQ 2.x.